# config parser python

Tags: python

I have a cfg file which has 10 sections..and each of the section has similar fields.

```
[sec1]
id:...
[sec2]
id..

...
```

So right now.. I am  doing something like..

```
config_instance = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
id1 = config_instance.get("sec1","id")
id2 = config_instance.get("sec2","id")
```

and so on

Is there a better more pythonic way to do this.. that it automatically reads all the sections and extracts this feature??

Thanks

Comment: Assuming Python 2.X, unless you require backwards compatibility with existing code you should probably be using `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the sections have it (or if you know a list of sections that have an id field), you can do something like:

```
sections=config_instance.sections()
ids=[config_instance.get(sec,'id') for sec in sections]
```

you can then unpack them if you want, but I prefer the list:

```
id1,id2,... = ids
```

Or, you can do it as a dictionary (python 2.7+):

```
ids={ sec:config_instance.get(sec,'id') for sec in sections }
print ids['sec1']
```

It really just depends on how you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary with the sections as keys and the IDs as values.

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
ids    = {}
for section in config.sections():
    if config.has_option(section, "id"):
        ids[section] = config.get(section, "id")
```